# How do I convert my swf to apk with certificate?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, flashdevelop

I have made an app using flashDevelop and Flash cs6, the swf has been put in my "bin" folder. I would like to convert my swf to a apk with certificate using flash cs6,

Is there a way to:

1. open a new flash cs6 mobile air document
2. load the swf
3. Set up the certificate and publish it as an apk.

Please note: For some reason I can not test the app from flash cs6, if I do it just shows the first scene. I can only test my game from flashDevelop as my document class is set there.

I have tried setting my document class in flash cs6 but I got errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to just replace the .swf file within an apk one, as this means you can create whatever app you want by switching it's core. That's why there are those certificates, because the client must be sure that this app is the one that has been published by the developer, not a faked one wrapped in old name.

Why would you ever need this? Just publish your application with your .swf as a root document, and it will be automatically wrapped in a new .apk file.